# When deploying Angular App to Azure (using 'Deploy to Azure' extension in VS Code)m environment.ts settings are replaced

Tags: angular, azure, deployment

When deploying an Angular App (i.e. mysite.com) to Azure (using 'Deploy to Azure' extension in VS Code), a setting  for an api url in the environment.ts file (myapi.com) is not being used whenever its accessed in the app.

It's being replaced with the url of the app im deploying to Azure (mysite.com), so im getting a 404 as the apis are on myapi.com, not mysite.com.

Could anyone please suggest how I get the Angular app to retrieve the correct setting from the environment.ts file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

inside environment files, contains `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`, when you run `ng build --prod`, angular generate build using only `environment.prod.ts` and do not `environemnt.ts`, put your env files inside `environment.prod.ts`, that way your environments going to be right :)

Comment: Many thanks @Lucas Sartori for replying, but my settings for the prod site are already in the environment.prod.ts file (are the same in all environments files).  

When I browse the deployed Angular code on Azure, all the environments files have the correct setting, but infuriatingly - they are not used.  

My environment.prod.ts file:


`export const environment = {
  production: true,
  domainApi: 'https://myapi.azurewebsites.net'
};` 

The '**domainApi**' value used by the site when running is different from above. Do you have any idea whats causing this? thanks again

Comment: maybe inside yours component is not calling right environment or is static in source, also check how is in  import=>
 `import {environment} from '../environments/environment'; `
and check inside angular.json inside 'projects.yourProjectName.architect.build.configurations.production.fileReplacements' if is right